# String or Binary Data would be truncated SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, binary, truncate

I have a table

Table1:

```
someColumnName0 char(10)     DoesNotAllowNull
someColumnName1 char(20)     AllowsNull
someColumnName2 char(20)     AllowsNull
....
...
...
someColumnNameN char(100)    AllowsNull
```

I got this error

> String or Binary value would be truncated....

and I thought one of the values in one of the columns was exceeding size limit and I didn't know which column.

Since all the columns can take a NULL value, I started entering a row with just one value in the first column and I still got the same message even when I manually entered a value in the first column only.

I don't know what is going on and what am I missing.

Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Its not the columns that are exceeding a size limit, its the data.  What is the insert statement you are trying to do?  One field there is longer than your specified column length.  This can also happen if you are trying to insert Unicode data.

Comment: In addition, I think that the `char` may be giving you problems.  Have you tried `varchar`?

Comment: include your insert statement?

Comment: How about posting the full CREATE TABLE DDL (including any DEFAULT CONSTRAINTS) as well as the INSERT statement?

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?